# Choosing the right Magento CE version considering the budget

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-2.1, magento-ce

I am looking to to develop a small scale e-commerce solution using Magento CE with drastic budget constraints.

I don't need much functionality either, just listing of products, invoice generation, integration with PayPal. So i am assuming i will have to utilize maximum free extensions.

So my question is Which CE version has most free extensions available, so i can progress through without spending much. If its not an hindrance than i would like to use latest 2.1 build. But if it has less numbers of free extensions then i will have to re-consider using older builds.

Answer (score 0):

Most free extensions are available in 1.9 but keep in mind that End of Life date is not specified, but could be issued by Magento team anytime, which would give 18 month of Magento 1.x support before they will stop issuing patches and updates.

If you are planning to use your store for more than 2 years then go for Magento 2.1.x, developers are actively developing extensions Its a progressive system, you will love it. Potentially it has a lot of undiscovered bugs, but its all manageable if one desires. Expect patches and updates on regular basis.

But if you project is **short-term**, say less than 2 years, then go for 1.9.3.6 and get the most out of it. Its a great system with tons of bugs fixed, and tons of extensions available for cheap or even free.

Hope I was of help.